# Using Baire Category to analyze the efficiency of the Simplex Method

Tags: linear-programming, topology, simplex

I read from  [the wiki page of the Simplex Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) that we can "use Baire category theory from general topology, and to show that (topologically) "most" matrices can be solved by the simplex algorithm in a polynomial number of steps."

It looks exciting, but there is no reference on the wiki page and I can't find a reference either. Could you please give me a reference?

Comment: Hmm. It was introduced in [this edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Simplex_algorithm&type=revision&diff=420535791&oldid=420516031), which does not give any hints as to where it comes from.

Comment: The first reference on a Google scholar for ["simplex" algorithm "linear programming" "baire" "category"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22&q=%22simplex%22+algorithm+%22linear+programming%22+%22baire%22+%22category%22&btnG=) seems to mention this (with the same wording), but also without much context or further citation.

Comment: @NealYoung That looks like someone just plagiarized the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Good point.  The article is from 2015, later than the wikipedia edit in 2011, and the wording is the same.

Comment: [FWIW, I've added a comment to the talk page for that Wikipedia article suggesting that the statement about Baire Category theory be removed if no citation can be found.]